# error while running android studio v2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using the latest version of android studio but I face these errors when I want to run even  a "hello world" app

---

> emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start init: Could not find
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB! getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find
>   GLES 1.x config! Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string! Could
>   not initialize emulated framebufferWarning: requested ram_size 4096M
>   too big, reduced to 1024M emulator: WARNING: Decreasing RAM size to
>   4096MB emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified
>   minimum of 256MB emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 1024MB Hax
>   is enabled Hax ram_size 0x40000000 HAX is working and emulator runs in
>   fast virt mode.

---

can any body help me to fix these errors

Comment: I see warnings, and complaints about the GLES 1.x config. You should explain what you're trying to do and what isn't working -- those messages might be unrelated.

Comment: I just try to run a very small application on android studio but I can't do it even a hello work application for 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The WARNING did say :

> VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 256MB emulator

Open your AVD Manager, increase your Heap size above than 256MB.

> Warning: requested ram_size 4096M too big, reduced to 1024M emulator: WARNING: Decreasing RAM size to 4096MB emulator

I guess total RAM on your machine is 4GB, so you can't set the RAM for emulator 4GB too! It will make your machine run slow as the emulator already took all of it. Please use the value as recommended, 2GB already nice.

Hope this help.

Comment: but I set the ram size on 1024 while I create a device in ADV manager

Comment: @Arya2010 how much is your total RAM? It's better to set it  between 2048MB and your total RAM.